# How to export data from data tables in a different format?

Tags: jquery, html

How to export data from data tables in different formats like Copy, CSV, Excel, PDF, Print?
Kindly help me to do it for the following example to export it in different formats like excel csv print and pdf for the following example

```js
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
 

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
            var api = this.api(), data;
 
           
            var intVal = function ( i ) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                        i : 0;
            };
 
          
            total = api
                .column( 4 )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                } );
 
        
            pageTotal = api
                .column( 4, { page: 'current'} )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
 
         
            $( api.column( 4 ).footer() ).html(
                '$'+pageTotal +' ( $'+ total +' total)'
            );
        }
    } );
} );
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<title>Footer Call Back</title>
</head>






<body>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
 
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4" style="text-align:right">Total:</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
 
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger</td>
                <td>Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett</td>
                <td>Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton</td>
                <td>Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric</td>
                <td>Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi</td>
                <td>Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle</td>
                <td>Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod</td>
                <td>Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona</td>
                <td>Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen</td>
                <td>Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya</td>
                <td>Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jena</td>
                <td>Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quinn</td>
                <td>Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Charde</td>
                <td>Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Haley</td>
                <td>Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tatyana</td>
                <td>Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael</td>
                <td>Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Paul</td>
                <td>Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gloria</td>
                <td>Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bradley</td>
                <td>Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dai</td>
                <td>Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>$217,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jenette</td>
                <td>Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>$345,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Yuri</td>
                <td>Berry</td>
                <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>$675,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Caesar</td>
                <td>Vance</td>
                <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>$106,450</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Doris</td>
                <td>Wilder</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>$85,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Angelica</td>
                <td>Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin</td>
                <td>Joyce</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>$92,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer</td>
                <td>Chang</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>$357,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brenden</td>
                <td>Wagner</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$206,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Fiona</td>
                <td>Green</td>
                <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$850,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shou</td>
                <td>Itou</td>
                <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>$163,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michelle</td>
                <td>House</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>$95,400</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Suki</td>
                <td>Burks</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$114,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Prescott</td>
                <td>Bartlett</td>
                <td>Technical Author</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$145,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin</td>
                <td>Cortez</td>
                <td>Team Leader</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$235,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Martena</td>
                <td>Mccray</td>
                <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>$324,050</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Unity</td>
                <td>Butler</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$85,675</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Howard</td>
                <td>Hatfield</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$164,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hope</td>
                <td>Fuentes</td>
                <td>Secretary</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$109,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Vivian</td>
                <td>Harrell</td>
                <td>Financial Controller</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$452,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Timothy</td>
                <td>Mooney</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$136,200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jackson</td>
                <td>Bradshaw</td>
                <td>Director</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>$645,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Olivia</td>
                <td>Liang</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>$234,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bruno</td>
                <td>Nash</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$163,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sakura</td>
                <td>Yamamoto</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>$139,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Thor</td>
                <td>Walton</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>$98,540</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Finn</td>
                <td>Camacho</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$87,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Serge</td>
                <td>Baldwin</td>
                <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>$138,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zenaida</td>
                <td>Frank</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>$125,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zorita</td>
                <td>Serrano</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$115,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer</td>
                <td>Acosta</td>
                <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>$75,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cara</td>
                <td>Stevens</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>$145,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hermione</td>
                <td>Butler</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$356,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lael</td>
                <td>Greer</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$103,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jonas</td>
                <td>Alexander</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$86,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shad</td>
                <td>Decker</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael</td>
                <td>Bruce</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Donna</td>
                <td>Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28410443/datatables-how-to-add-the-copy-csv-pdf-print-and-add-input-save-in-csv-to/28422329#28422329 i guess

Answer (score 1):

You need to include these :

1. jquery.js
2. jquery.dataTables.js
3. dataTables.tableTools.js
4. jquery.dataTables.css
5. dataTables.tableTools.css

As per [datatable documentation](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/examples/collection.html), add the following 2 options to your script:

```
 $('#example').dataTable( {
    "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    "tableTools": {
        "sSwfPath": "/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
    },
    "footerCallback": ..........
```

Comment: After including the above script also the its not working as they showed in data tables website even the buttons are not appearing in the screen .

Comment: Hi, do you add http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/js/dataTables.tableTools.js to your page?

Comment: No i don't the use of it ??

Comment: Read this : http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/examples/collection.html

Comment: i read it but when i include the jquery.js it not working is there any way to solve it

Comment: What's about console after you run page? can you give me more details? May you need update your jquery library and its Migrate version.

Comment: no nothing is shown in the console if i don't use jquery.js except save option all are working as provided in link above(datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/…) if i use jquery.js nothing works. How to solve it?

Comment: Let remove the current jquery library  and then add <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>. This is the jQuery online version.

Comment: Also remove this line : <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>.

Comment: Even after i followed the steps as you told the same error copying, saving in excel,pdf and CSV is not happening and print option alone is working fine. I removed the line <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> and added the other two lines <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script> <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script> though it is not working. How to solve this ?